# Insert new DataRow with autoincrement Primary Key with C# (OleDB)

Tags: c#, ms-access, insert, oledb, primary-key

I' m trying to insert a new DataRow (locally stored in a DataSet) to a Access table with C#. The table is also created by this app and has 3 columns:

- `ID` (integer, primary key, `Required` is set to `No` though I've set it as primary key)
- `Name` (string)
- `Money` (int)

My current code looks like that:

```
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataAdapter da;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataView dv = new DataView();
        DataRow row;

        string Con = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=";
        string path = "V:\\ProjectProgress\\Test.mdb";
        con.ConnectionString = Con + path;

        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        cmd.Connection = con;

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, Name, Money FROM Test";
        da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Test");
        da.Fill(ds, "Test");

        ds.Tables["Test"].Columns[0].AutoIncrement = true;
        ds.Tables["Test"].Columns[0].AutoIncrementSeed = -1;
        ds.Tables["Test"].Columns[0].AutoIncrementStep = -1;

        dv.Table = ds.Tables["Test"];

        row = ds.Tables["Test"].NewRow();
        row["Name"] = "Huber";
        row["Money"] = 100;

        ds.Tables["Test"].Rows.Add(row);

        string strOLE = "INSERT INTO Test ([Name], [Money]) Values(@Name, @Money)";

        OleDbCommand cmdi = new OleDbCommand(strOLE, con);
        cmdi.Parameters.Add("@Name", OleDbType.VarChar, 25, "Name");
        cmdi.Parameters.Add("@Money", OleDbType.Integer, 4, "Money");


        da.InsertCommand = cmdi;

        da.Update(ds.Tables["Test"]);

        con.Close();
```

When updating I'm always getting a

> Index or primary key cannot contain a Null value

error.

Setting the `Required` value of the `ID` column to `Yes`, will throw a

> Index or Primary Key Cannot Contain a Null Value

error.

How can I let Access assign the right primary key and how do I get the new value back into my dataset?

Using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is not possible in Access as far as I know and found in some forums.

(Working with Visual C# Express 2010, Access 2003)

Answer (score 1):

The following is complete working test code to illustrate the procedure. All we need to do is provide an `OleDbDataAdapter.SelectCommand` that includes the primary key and the columns we want to update, and the `OleDbCommandBuilder` object will create the INSERT statement for us:

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace oleDbTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string myConnectionString;
            myConnectionString =
                    @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                    @"Data Source=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb;";

            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection())
            {
                con.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
                con.Open();

                using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                using (OleDbCommandBuilder bld = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da))
                {
                    bld.QuotePrefix = "[";  // these are
                    bld.QuoteSuffix = "]";  //   important!

                    da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(
                            "SELECT [ID], [Name], [Money] " +
                            "FROM [Test] " +
                            "WHERE False",
                            con);
                    using (System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable("Test"))
                    {
                        // create an empty DataTable with the correct structure
                        da.Fill(dt);

                        System.Data.DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                        dr["Name"] = "Huber";
                        dr["Money"] = 100;
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                        da.Update(dt);  // write new row back to database
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that your problem might be that both `AutoIncrementSeed` and `AutoIncrementStep` are set to a negative value of `-1`. Try setting both to a positive value.

[EDIT]

Second thought, you might want to try the `OleDbCommandBuilder` ([MSDN documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommandbuilder.aspx)). It creates your INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements automatically using the column information of your DataSet.
At my former employer we used `OleDbCommandBuilder` all the time when working with Access and it worked like a charm, even with auto increment fields.

Comment: Positive seed and step doesn't change anything - I still get the "Index or primary key cannot contain a Null value" error.

When I take the ID from my dataset ("INSERT INTO Test ([ID], [Name], [Money]) Values(@ID, @Name, @Money)") Access takes this value and doesn't assign a valid ID so I get a error if the primary key already exists...